# How can I count instances of $f(x)=0$ from $x=0$ to $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, measure-theory, functions, quasiperiodic-function

I posted a question in such a garbled form that I thought I should repost separately. I have deleted the other post just to remove it from consideration. Apologies for that.

I am playing with a complicated quasi-periodic equation, $f(x)$, which boils down to a summation of sines and cosines. I can't give the full equation because I'm still searching for the right formulation. So for now let's call it

$$f(x)=\sum_{a=0}^b (cos(ax)+sin(ax))$$

Is it possible to produce a formula $g(x)$ that delivers the number of instances, $n$, where $f(x)=0$?

I realise this particular $f(x)$ is trivial, but I'm searching for a solution that will work with much more complicated quasi-periodic functions of the same general form. Or is my only option to write code with a loop counter?

Comment: The other question is not "marked ... as answered." You deleted it.

Comment: Apologies. Yes. It was a garbled mess.

Comment: If any of you have any suggestions (a) I'd be deeply grateful and (b) please don't take silence as lack of response - I'm on UK time and I'll check back on this thread in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Playing, as usual.

Since
$\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)
=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sin(z)+\cos(z)
&=\sqrt{2}(\sin(z)\cos(\pi/4)+\cos(z)\sin(\pi/4))\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\sin(z+\pi/4)\\
&=\sqrt{2}(\sin(z)\sin(\pi/4)+\cos(z)\cos(\pi/4))\\
&=-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\cos(z-\pi/4)\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\sum_{a=0}^b (\cos(ax)+\sin(ax))\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{a=0}^b \sin(ax+\pi/4)\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}Im(e^{i\pi/4}\sum_{a=0}^b e^{iax})\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}Im(\frac1{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)\sum_{a=0}^b (e^{ix})^a\\
&=\frac1{2}Im((1+i)\dfrac{1-e^{ix(b+1)}}{1-e^{ix}})
\qquad\text{I could stop here, but I'm feeling masochistic}\\
&=\frac1{2}Im(\dfrac{(1+i)(1-e^{ix(b+1)})(1-e^{-ix})}{(1-e^{ix})(1-e^{-ix})})\\
&=\frac1{2}Im(\dfrac{(1+i)(1-e^{ix(b+1)})(1-e^{-ix})}{1-(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})+1})\\
&=\frac1{2}Im(\dfrac{(1+i)(1-e^{ix(b+1)}-e^{-ix}+e^{ixb})}{2-2\cos(x)})\\
&=\frac1{2}Im(\dfrac{(1+i)(1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(-x)+\cos(bx))+i(-\sin(x(b+1))-\sin(-x)+\sin(bx)))}{2-2\cos(x)})\\
&=\dfrac1{2(2-2\cos(x))}Im((1+i)(1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx))+i(-\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx))))\\
&=\dfrac1{4(1-\cos(x))}Im((1+i)(1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx))\\
&\quad +i(-\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx))))\\
&=\dfrac1{4(1-\cos(x))}Im(
(1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx))\\
&\quad +i(-\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx)))\\
&\quad+i((1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx))\\
&\quad +i(-\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx))))\\
&=\dfrac1{4(1-\cos(x))}Im(
(1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx))\\
&\quad +i(-\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx)))\\
&\quad+i(1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx))\\
&\quad -(-\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx))))\\
&=\dfrac1{4(1-\cos(x))}Im(
(1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx))\\
&\quad -(-\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx))))\\
&\quad +i(-\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx))\\
&\quad+1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx)))\\
&=\dfrac1{4(1-\cos(x))}(
 -\sin(x(b+1))+\sin(x)+\sin(bx)\\
&\quad +1-\cos(x(b+1)-\cos(x)+\cos(bx)))\\
&=\dfrac1{4(1-\cos(x))}(
1 -(\sin(x(b+1))+\cos(x(b+1))+(\sin(x)-\cos(x))+\sin(bx)+\cos(bx)))\\
&=\dfrac1{4(1-\cos(x))}(
1 -\sqrt{2}(\sin(x(b+1)+\pi/4)+(\sin(x-\pi/4))+\sin(bx+\pi/4)))\\
\end{array}
$

I figure that
this has a 10% chance
of being correct.